# R rowSums and select inside mutate function dplyr

Tags: r, select, dplyr, sum, mutate

I am trying to select columns in my dataframe and add them together if they exist. I tried

```
newdf4 %>% select(any_of(contains(c("adSize_300 x 600","adSize_160 x 600","adSize_120 x 600","adSize_125 x 600")))) %>% mutate(vertical_sizes=rowSums(.))
```

It gives me a separate output of the two columns that exist and the new vertical_sizes column created:

```
 adSize_300 x 600 adSize_160 x 600 vertical_sizes
1                  1                0              1
2                  0                0              0
3                  0                0              0
4                  0                0              0
5                  0                1              1
6                  0                0              0
7                  1                0              1
8                  0                0              0
9                  0                0              0
10                 0                0              0
11                 0                0              0
```

However, I want the new vertical sizes column to be added to my original newdf4 dataframe.
I am trying:

```
newdf4 %>% mutate(vertical_sizes = rowSums(select(any_of(contains(c("adSize_300 x 600","adSize_160 x 600","adSize_120 x 600","adSize_125 x 600"))))))
```

But i receive this error:

```
Error in `mutate_cols()`:
! Problem with `mutate()` column `vertical_sizes`.
i `vertical_sizes = rowSums(...)`.
x `any_of()` must be used within a *selecting* function.
i See <https://tidyselect.r-lib.org/reference/faq-selection-context.html>.
Caused by error:
! `any_of()` must be used within a *selecting* function.
i See <https://tidyselect.r-lib.org/reference/faq-selection-context.html>.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Please let me know if there is another approach to this. Thank you!

Comment: change `select` to `across` ie `rowSums(across(contains(...)))`

Comment: I'm not going to spend to the time parse that frame, the spaced embedded in the column names mean that we can't just copy and paste it into R. If onyambu's comment does not resolve it for you, please edit your question and add the output from `dput(newdf4)` (optionally `dput(head(newdf4,11))` if large).

Comment: In hindsight, *"I'm not going to spend to the time"* is both grammatically `bad` and comes across much harsher than I intended. What I mean is *"it's hard to use the data as-is, and I just ran out of time to play with this problem, please provide it in a different format"*. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

`select` inside of `mutate` requires data as its first argument, it will not *infer* or assume that it should look in the enclosing environment. For instance, when one does something like

```r
mtcars %>%
  select(cyl, mpg, disp)
```

The `%>%` is placing the data in the first argument of the RHS function, so this is more-aptly shown as

```r
mtcars %>%
  select(., cyl, mpg, disp)
```

where `.` indicates where the data is going. `%>%` allows one to specify *where* in the RHS expression the data should be placed (generally it works so long as the `.` is not placed within nested expressions).

Having said that, your use of `select` places the `any_of` in the first argument, which is (obviously) not going to work.

I suggest we use `cur_data()` (one of dplyr's context-dependent expressions) as the first argument.

Data:

```r
read.table(text = '
     adSize_300x600 adSize_160x600 vertical_sizes
1                  1             0              1
2                  0             0              0
3                  0             0              0
4                  0             0              0
5                  0             1              1
6                  0             0              0
7                  1             0              1
8                  0             0              0
9                  0             0              0
10                 0             0              0
11                 0             0              0')
```

Code:

```r
newdf4 %>%
  mutate(
    vertical_sizes = rowSums(
      select(cur_data(),
             contains(c("adSize_300x600", "adSize_160x600", "adSize_120x600", "adSize_125x600")))
    )
  )
#    adSize_300x600 adSize_160x600 vertical_sizes
# 1               1              0              1
# 2               0              0              0
# 3               0              0              0
# 4               0              0              0
# 5               0              1              1
# 6               0              0              0
# 7               1              0              1
# 8               0              0              0
# 9               0              0              0
# 10              0              0              0
# 11              0              0              0
```